# Why we use two indirection operator to access array of string

Tags: c

Suppose

```
char *p;
char a[] = "Hello";

p = a;
```

Here **p** will have address of **a** and its point to the first element of the string **Hello**

*In other words we need one indirection operator to access first element of the string **Hello***

When we have array of strings why we need two **Indirection** operator while array is nothing but bunch of memory location which have same data type

Comment: Are you thinking of an array of constant-length arrays of chars or of an array of pointers to strings/chararrays?

Comment: While the address of `a` and the address of the first element of `a` are the same, they are semantically different. Using the correct terminology is kind of important in programming. So saying "here `p` will point to the first element of the array `a`" might be better.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you are thinking of with some code, similar to the code you provided to illustrate the first half of your comparison.

Comment: Not a fully fleshed out answer, but you don't actually need two indirections. You can treat the whole string array as a long list of chars if you want to. Try it out :)

Comment: `char *a[] = { "Hello", "Goodbye" };` only has one indirection operator, not two ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane two to access the char **a

Comment: @P__J__ the question is unclear and the code doesn't show what is meant hence my smiley thing. `a[1][5]` doesn't need any stars at all to access `'y'` in my example.

Comment: @Yunnosch Please explain in both the cases and with due respect I think array of string means array of variable length string (K&R used this word directly)

Comment: Whether you need double indirection when working with an array of strings depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: @lucidbrot, that depends on what is meant by an "array of strings".  What you describe is true for arrays of arrays of `char`, and those can be considered arrays of strings, but it is *not* true for arrays of `char *`, which is what I think of first when I hear "array of strings".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following array of strings:

```
char* greeting[] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

The above code could result (on a simple architecture) in a memory layout like this:

```
1000  'H'  'e'  'l'  'l'
1004  'o'  00   'W'  'o'
1008  'r'  'l'  'd'  00
100c  10   00   10   06
```

The array-of-strings `greeting` is at memory address 100c, and consists of two elements: `greeting[0]`, a `char*` that points at address 1000, and `greeting[1]`, a *separate* `char*` pointing at address 1006.
To get to an individual *letter* requires two indirections...

```
char c = greeting[1][2];
```

...because getting the character is a two stage process. First we get the correct string, then we get the correct character from that string. Essentially the above line is equivalent to...

```
char* p = *(greeting+1);
char c = *(p+2);
```

Each line performs one indirection. In the first case, (bearing in mind that pointers are two-byte entities on my simplified system architecture) we need the second member from the `greeting` array, so we read two bytes from address 100e and get a value of 1006, which is stored in `p` . In the second, we need the third member from a char array at address `p`, i.e. 1006,  so we read one byte from address 1008 and get a value of 'r'.

Every time you add an additional array dimension, you will need another level of indirection (or array indexing) to get back to the actual data (bytes, in this case).

Comment: What if we have 3rd String

Comment: I believe what @Bhaskar was originally asking is this: Why can't we just say we want the character at memory address 1008?
I believe that we could do that, but I failed so horribly at a sample program that I didn't finish my answer

Comment: If you simply add a third string, then the same principles apply. If you add a third _dimension_ to the array, then things get more complicated when defining and initializing the data, depending on whether you're trying to create a "rectangular" array (NxM group of strings) or "jagged" array (N lists of strings, each of different length).

Comment: @lucidbot, we can, but how would we know that we want 1008?

Comment: @lucidbrot Exactly Thank You for rephrasing it and making it clear

Comment: @TimRandall But atleast we can get the first string because we have its address

Comment: @TimRandall I was thinking about pointer arithmetics. `((long) myArray[0])+(9*sizeof(char))` for the 9th entry

Comment: Yes, you can get the first string with `char* p = greeting[0];` or the first character in the first string with `char c = greeting[0][0];`

Comment: @TimRandall I think I got the point Derefrencing is important because at first array name point to whole array after first Derefrencing we reach the level of string and after further Derefrencing we reach at level of characters. So Derefrencing says at what level we want to work

Comment: @Bhaskar yes, I think that's it. `greeting` is an array of arrays of char, `greeting[i]` is an array of char, and `greeting[i][j]` is a char

Answer (score 5):

As I think you mean it, for any array or pointer 'a' and index `i` the expression `a[i]` is exactly equal to `*(a + i)`.

That means e.g. `a[0]` is equal to `*(a + 0)`. And `*(a + 0)` is equal to `*(a)` which is equal to `*a`.

If `a` is an array of characters, as shown in your example, then `*a` is indeed the value of the first element. But if `a` is an array of arrays, like

```
char a[2][4] = { "Foo", "Bar" };
```

then `*a` is is *still* the first element of `a`, and in this case it's *another array* (the one containing the string `"Foo"`). And using the same logic as above, since `*a` is another array then `**a` is the first element of that nested array, which in my example is the letter `'F'`.

That's why you need "two indirection" to reach the first letter of the first array.

Oh, and going backward, `**a` (with my arrays of arrays) becomes equal to `a[0][0]`.

---

If we take our array of arrays

```
char a[2][4] = { "Foo", "Bar" };
```

and show how it would be laid out in memory, it would be like this (with pointers added):

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'F' | 'o' | 'o' |  0  | 'B' | 'a' | 'r' |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
^                       ^
|                       |
&a[0][0]                &a[1][0]
|                       |
&a[0]                   &a[1]
|
&a
```

If we take the pointers `&a`, `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` they all point to the same location. ***But*** they are not the same type!

- The expression `&a` is a pointer to the whole array `a`, its type is `char (*)[2][4]`
- The expression `&a[0]` is a pointer to the first sub-array, and its type is `char (*)[4]`
- And the expression `&a[0][0]` is a pointer to the first character in the first array, and its type is `char *`

The "dereferencing" made means different things for the different pointers.

Comment: But the thing is &a[0] and &a[0][0] are same so why we are dereferencing same address two times

Comment: @Bhaskar they are not the same. They have the same addres but have different types

Comment: Because, @Bhaskar, the *types* of the expressions `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` are different.  The type affects how the value is interpreted in larger expressions of which one or the other is part.

Comment: @Bhaskar Added a small explanation about the differences

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But isn't dereferencing  mean pointer(i.e. an address) get the value from that memory block which my pointer variable points to ? Please clarify it little bit

Comment: @Bhaskar I'm sorry but I don't really know what you mean, so I don't know how to explain it differently.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Suppose an array a[2][3] the value of a is the starting address. So when we dereference it we got the value what that starting address have so why to derefrence it again

Comment: @Bhaskar Dereferencing an array object is not the same as dereferencing a pointer. If you have `char x; char b; char a[5]; char *p = a;`,  then `x = b;` and `x = a[0];` both involve one read operation and one write operation. But `x = p[0];` involves two read operations and one write operation. An array object does not have a hidden pointer object behind the scenes.

Comment: @Bhaskar `a`, `a[0]` and `a[0][0]` give you *different things*. They are not the same. Also remember that arrays are not in themselves pointers. They can *decay* to a pointer (to its first element), but they're not pointers.

Comment: @Bhaskar To clarify what a wrote above, dereferencing an array object is not the same as dereferencing a pointer _object_. An array decays to a pointer in an expression (except for a few special expressions), but this pointer is just like a number (a memory address) rather than like a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your problem but it probably comes from the misunderstanding of the concept of pointers and arrays.

Arrays can decay to the pointer values and I hope that example program will give you some example of it. As you see the multidimensional arrays decay to the pointer with same level of indirection. Because the array is just the continues piece of memory the compiler takes all the necessary address calculations

```
int main ()
{
  char *a[] = { "11111", "22222", "33333", "44444"};
  char b[][10] = { "11111", "22222", "33333", "44444"};


  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
      printf("i = %d -> **(a + i) = %c ",i , **(a + i));
      printf("*a[i] = %c ", *a[i]);
      printf("a[i][0] = %c ", a[i][0]);
      printf("*(a + i) = %s ", *(a + i));
      printf("a[i] = %s\n", a[i]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
      printf("i = %d -> **(b + i) = %c ", i, **(b + i));
      printf("*b[i] = %c ", *b[i]);
      printf("b[i][0] = %c ", b[i][0]);
      printf("*(b + i) = %s ", *(b + i));
      printf("b[i] = %s\n", b[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and the result

```
i = 0 -> **(a + i) = 1 *a[i] = 1 a[i][0] = 1 *(a + i) = 11111 a[i] = 11111                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 1 -> **(a + i) = 2 *a[i] = 2 a[i][0] = 2 *(a + i) = 22222 a[i] = 22222                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 2 -> **(a + i) = 3 *a[i] = 3 a[i][0] = 3 *(a + i) = 33333 a[i] = 33333                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 3 -> **(a + i) = 4 *a[i] = 4 a[i][0] = 4 *(a + i) = 44444 a[i] = 44444                                                                                                                                                                                  


i = 0 -> **(b + i) = 1 *b[i] = 1 b[i][0] = 1 *(b + i) = 11111 b[i] = 11111                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 1 -> **(b + i) = 2 *b[i] = 2 b[i][0] = 2 *(b + i) = 22222 b[i] = 22222                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 2 -> **(b + i) = 3 *b[i] = 3 b[i][0] = 3 *(b + i) = 33333 b[i] = 33333                                                                                                                                                                                  
i = 3 -> **(b + i) = 4 *b[i] = 4 b[i][0] = 4 *(b + i) = 44444 b[i] = 44444
```

But arrays are not pointers

Here you have another example showing the difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  char *a = "11111";
  char *c = "aaaaa";
  char b[] = "2222";

void foo(char **ptr, char *new)
{
    *ptr = new;
}

int main ()
{
    foo(&a, c);
    foo(&b, c);

    printf("a = %s, b = %s\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

and the result:

```
 a = aaaaa, b = D@
```

you may also try to compile

```
a++;
b++;
```

and see what the compiler says.